# Simpler way for this query: If {current date} is a {weekly/fortnightly/monthly} repeat/multiple of {start_date}

Tags: php, mysql

We have a table for **scheduled_jobs**, this table includes the following two columns:

Repeat Type: Weekly/Fortnightly/Monthly

Beginning Date: The date it will repeat from, i.e. if repeat type is monthly and beginning date is set to 2015-12-05, it will repeat on the fifth of each month.

The below query is a snippet of code that is currently being used:

```
<?php
    foreach(range(1,100) as $num)
    {
        $numtimestwo = $num * 2;

        $query = "SELECT * FROM scheduled_jobs WHERE deleted != TRUE AND ((DATE_ADD(DATE(beginning_date), INTERVAL $num MONTH) = CURDATE() AND repeat_type = 'monthly') OR (DATE_ADD(DATE(beginning_date), INTERVAL $numtimestwo WEEK) = CURDATE() AND repeat_type = 'fortnightly') OR (DATE_ADD(DATE(beginning_date), INTERVAL $num WEEK) = CURDATE() AND repeat_type = 'weekly'))";

        // If result is not empty, process the scheduled job
    }
?>
```

But I've noticed some problems, this will eventually stop working as beginning_date gets older and older, and it seems like there should be a better solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue using [PHP's diff method](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) for DateTime objects.

The below function takes a $type ("daily/weekly/fortnightly/monthly/six months/yearly") and a $beginning_date (date string).

eg. If you have a date "2010-01-01" with the type "monthly", that you want to return true for the first of every month, this will work. A date of "2015-06-05" with the type "weekly" will return true every 7 days after that date.

```
function checkInterval($type, $beginning_date)
{
    // Get DateTime for today, and DateTime object for $beginngin_date input
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $today = new DateTime($today);
    $beginning_date = new DateTime($beginning_date);
    // Diff the two dates, and get the save variables for the difference in days, months, years, as well as total days passed ($interval->days)
    $interval = $beginning_date->diff($today);
    $difference_d = $interval->d;
    $difference_m = $interval->m;
    $difference_y = $interval->y;
    $difference_total = $interval->days;
    // If beginning date is today, do not proceed
    if($difference_total < 1)
    {
            return false;
    }
    // If daily, return true all days
    if($type == "daily")
    {
            return true;
    // If weekly, Return true on the day difference being a multiple of 7 days or 0
    } else if($type == "weekly") {
            if($difference_d == "7" || $difference_d == "14" || $difference_d == "21" || $difference_d == "28" || $difference_d == "0")
            {
                    return true;
            }
    // If fortnightly, Return true on the day difference between a multiple of 14 days or 0
    } else if ($type == "fortnightly") {
            if($difference_d == "14" || $difference_d == "28" || $difference_d == "0")
            {
                    return true;
            }
    // If monthly, only return true when it is same day every month (0)
    } else if ($type == "monthly") {
            if($difference_d === 0)
            {
                    return true;
            }
    // If biannually, return true when there's a 6 month difference, and it's the same day of the month
    } else if ($type == "six months") {
            if($difference_m == "6" && $difference_d == "0")
            {
                    return true;
            }
    // Return true when year difference is greater than 0, and day and month are equal (0)
    } else if ($type == "yearly") {
            if($difference_d == "0" && $difference_m == "0" && $difference_y > 0)
            {
                    return true;
            }
    // Else no matches, return false
    } else {
            return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```